# jQuery-UI slider up down buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, slider

Didn't find the way to create up and down buttons for vertical slider, to make its appearance like as standard scroller.

Is solution below suitable? Or are there any other ways?

```
function scroll(step)
{

    if (step > 0)
    {
        if ($("#slider").slider('value') <= (100 - step))
        {
            $("#slider").slider('value', $("#slider").slider('value') + step);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if ($("#slider").slider('value') >= Math.abs(step))
        {
            $("#slider").slider('value', $("#slider").slider('value') + step);
        }       
    }


    return false;   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have certainly works...but if you're worried about the range capping, [slider already does this internally](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/1.8.6/ui/jquery.ui.slider.js#L462), so you can just do this:

```
function scroll(step) {
  var s = $("#slider");
  s.slider('value', s.slider('value') + step);
  return false;   
}
```

Also note that even *setting* the value returns it (the capped value), so you can do this for example:

```
function scroll(step) {
  var s = $("#slider");
  var newValue = s.slider('value', s.slider('value') + step);
  alert("The new value is: " + newValue);
  return false;   
}
```

So for example if the range is `0-100` and you're at `90`, a step of `10` *or more* would always result in a `newValue` of `100`.